# How to modify this Horizontal ViewPager transformer into Vertical transformer?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-viewpager, android-support-library

this is the code I have.It works fine for Horizontal transformation animation.  I want to transform my ViewPager transition animation vertically.

```
public class AccordionPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
@Override
public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
    // Counteract the default slide transition
    page.setTranslationX(-position * page.getWidth());

    page.setPivotX(position < 0 ? 0 : page.getWidth());
    page.setScaleX(1 - Math.abs(position));
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for ViewPager,

```
        if (position < -1) { 
            page.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 1) { 
            page.setAlpha(1);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            page.setTranslationX(page.getWidth() * -position);

            //Set Y position to swipe in from top
            float yPosition = position * page.getHeight();
            page.setTranslationY(yPosition);

        } else { 
            page.setAlpha(0);
        }
```

Or you can also use [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) It provides single line code to make scrolling vertical,

```
myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
```